# total with divide in 4 columns equal to div number

Tags: javascript, jquery

we are develop small graph which is divide in four columns if input is any number and all four columns fill the full width.

image:- 
[image]

Html Code:-

```
<div class="progressArea">
   <div class="leadCon"> Sales Cycle Length <span><b>18</b> days</span></div>
   <div class="proArea">
      <div data-target="1" class="color1">3</div>
      <div data-target="2" class="color2">5</div>
      <div data-target="3" class="color3">7</div>
      <div data-target="4" class="color4">3</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

jquery Code:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var totalArea = $('.progressArea .leadCon b').text();
  var divArea = $('.proArea div').width();
  var div = totalArea/4;
  $('.proArea div').css('width', div);  
});
```

Comment: so what is the problem

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question or stated the actual problem nor what is or is not working. Please clarify.

Comment: the problem this that, i can't make all four columns with 100% with divide into four, you can see on the image too.. 18day divide into 4 but full width.

Comment: you want alle 4 divs the same length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get the addition of all values
2. use `each()` and traverse through each number
3. Divide each value with total and multiply it by 100, to get the width for that element and assign it to that element using `css()`

Below is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  createBars('containerId');
  createBars('containerId-2');
});

function createBars(containerId) {
  var total = 0;
  $('#' + containerId + ' div').each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).text());
  });

  $('#' + containerId + ' div').each(function() {
    var currentVal = $(this).text();
    var divideResult = (currentVal / total) * 100;
    $(this).css({
      'width': divideResult + '%'
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.proArea {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.proArea div {
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  float: left;
  padding: 4px 0;
}

.color1 {
  background: red;
}

.color2 {
  background: blue;
}

.color3 {
  background: green;
}

.color4 {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progressArea">
  <div class="leadCon"> Sales Cycle Length <span><b>18</b> days</span></div>
  <div class="proArea" id='containerId'>
    <div data-target="1" class="color1">3</div>
    <div data-target="2" class="color2">5</div>
    <div data-target="3" class="color3">7</div>
    <div data-target="4" class="color4">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="proArea" id='containerId-2'>
    <div data-target="1" class="color1">13</div>
    <div data-target="2" class="color2">25</div>
    <div data-target="3" class="color3">37</div>
    <div data-target="4" class="color4">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by `multiple`?

Comment: this is one block, if we have more the one block

Comment: @BharatNegi - You can change it to function. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use in CSS

```
.color1, .color2, .color3, .color4 { 
    width: 25%; 
    float: left; or display: inline-block;
}
```